# FreeCodeCamp Javascript calculator test suite | I don't know why I can't pass this test

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm doing that FCC javascript calculator test, and I'm just stuck.

my code seems to be working but test suite says I'm not getting half of it so I just wanted to ask if you guys can point me to a write direction.

Also I'm keep getting this msg:

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment.
```

But I don't know what it's referring to.

```
const equalStyle = {
  height: 120,
  backgroundColor: "#995ba4",
  bottom:7,
  position:"absolute"
};
const clearStyle = {backgroundColor: "#b83146"};
const equationStyle = {backgroundColor: "#b2b2b2"};
const equation = /[/*+-]/;
const confirmEquation = /[/*+-]$/;
const secondConfirm =/\d[x/+‑*]‑$/;
const negative = /[-]/;
const dotTester = /[.]/;
const prevTester = /^[/*-+]/;
      

class Main extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      totalVal:"",
      testVal:"0",
      displayVal:"0",
      prevVal:""
    }
    this.clickedVal = this.clickedVal.bind(this);
    this.calDisplay = this.calDisplay.bind(this);
  }
  
 calDisplay(val){
    if(this.state.displayVal == "0"){
      if(this.state.totalVal == ""){
        this.setState({
        totalVal: val
        })
      }
    } 
    else{
      this.setState({totalVal:this.state.totalVal + val})
    }
  }
  
  
 clickedVal(e){
    let clickVal = e.target.value;
    if (clickVal=="x"){clickVal = clickVal.replace("x", "*")};
   
    if(this.state.totalVal.includes("=")){
      this.setState({
        totalVal:"",
        testVal:"0",
        displayVal:"0"
      })
    }
   
  setTimeout(()=>{
      if(this.state.testVal == "0"&&!isNaN(parseInt(clickVal))){
        this.setState({ displayVal:clickVal, testVal:clickVal}, this.calDisplay(clickVal))
      }
      
      else if (!isNaN(parseInt(clickVal))){
      this.setState({ displayVal: this.state.displayVal + clickVal,testVal:this.state.displayVal + clickVal},this.calDisplay(clickVal))
      }
      /*equation stuff*/
      else if(equation.test(clickVal)){
          if(confirmEquation.test(this.state.totalVal)){
              if(negative.test(clickVal)){
                this.calDisplay(clickVal)
                this.setState({displayVal: clickVal, testVal:"0"})
              }
           
              else if(secondConfirm.test(this.state.totalVal)){
                  this.setState({
                      displayVal: clickVal, testVal:"0", totalVal: this.state.totalVal.slice(0, this.state.totalVal.length-2)
                    });
              setTimeout(()=>this.calDisplay(clickVal))
              }
            
              else{
                  this.setState({
                      displayVal: clickVal, testVal:"0", totalVal: this.state.totalVal.slice(0, this.state.totalVal.length-1)
                  });
              setTimeout(()=>this.calDisplay(clickVal))
              }
          }  
      
        else if (typeof(this.state.prevVal) == "number"  && this.state.displayVal =="0"){
            this.setState({displayVal:clickVal, testVal:"0"})
            this.calDisplay(this.state.prevVal+clickVal)
        }
        
        else{
            this.setState({displayVal:clickVal, testVal:"0"})
            this.calDisplay(clickVal);
        }
    }
      
      else if(clickVal == "."){
        if(confirmEquation.test(this.state.totalVal)){
          this.calDisplay("0.")
          this.setState({ displayVal: "0.", testVal: "0"})
      }
      else if (dotTester.test(this.state.displayVal)){
          this.setState({displayVal: this.state.displayVal ,testVal:this.state.displayVal})
      }
      else{
          this.calDisplay(clickVal);
          this.setState({displayVal: this.state.displayVal + clickVal,testVal:this.state.displayVal + clickVal})
      }
    }
      
      else if (clickVal == "="){
         
        let result = Math.round(1000000000000 * eval(this.state.totalVal)) / 1000000000000;
        this.setState({
          displayVal: result, testVal:"0", prevVal:result
        })
        this.calDisplay("="+result)
      }
      
      else if (clickVal == "AC"){
        this.setState({
          totalVal:"",
          testVal:"0",
          displayVal:"0",
          prevVal:""
      })
    }
   })    
  }
  
  render(){

    return(
      <div className = "calculatorBody" >
        <OutputDisplay formula = {this.state.totalVal}/>
        <InputDisplay currentValue = {this.state.displayVal} />
        <Buttons onClick = {this.clickedVal}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/arthur-lee945/pen/NWaebeV?editors=0111

This is my codepen for it.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when 'this.state.totalVal' is "5-2=3/2" at below codes(117 line).

```
let result = Math.round(1000000000000 * eval(this.state.totalVal)) / 1000000000000;
```

And you can check values of this variable by setting a breakpoint at 117 line in the source tab of your browser devtools.

Comment: It's worth adding that the *reason* for the error is that `=` is the assignment operator, and you can't assign to the result of `5-2`.